# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'SqfliteDatabaseBase' has no instance method 'insert' with matching arguments

Tags: flutter

`enter code here`error message below:
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'SqfliteDatabaseBase' has no instance method 'insert' with matching arguments.
Receiver: Instance of 'SqfliteDatabaseBase'
Tried calling: insert("notes.db", _Map len:4, ConflictAlgorithm: Instance of 'ConflictAlgorithm')
Found: insert(String, Map<String, Object?>, {String? nullColumnHack, ConflictAlgorithm? conflictAlgorithm}) => Future)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd7xD.png)

i tried changing the to map function but it dosent work

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';  
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

import '../models/notemodel.dart';

class DataBaseHelper {
static const dbname = 'notes.db';
static const dbversion = 1;

Future dbInit() async {
Database? database;
if (database != null) {
  return database;
} else {
  final database = openDatabase(
      join(
        await getDatabasesPath(),
        'notes.db',
      ),
      onCreate: onCreate,
      version: dbversion);
  return database;
}
}

onCreate(db, version) {
return db.execute(
    'CREATE TABLE notes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,title 
TEXT,description TEXT,date DATE)');
}

//insert notes
Future<void> insertNotes(Note note) async {
final db = await dbInit();

await db.insert(dbname, note.toMap(),
    ConflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
}

//retrieve notes
Future<List<Note>> getNote() async {
final db = await dbInit();
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('notes');
return List.generate(maps.length, (index) {
  return Note(
      id: maps[index]['id'],
      title: maps[index]['title'],
      description: maps[index]['description'],
      date: maps[index]['date']);
});
}

//edit note
Future<void> editNote(Note note) async {
final db = await dbInit();
await db.update('notes.db', note.toMap(), where: 'id=?', 
whereArgs: [note.id]);
}

//delete note

Future<void> deleteNote(int id) async {
final db = await dbInit();
await db.delete('notes.db', where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add full code in question instead of image

Comment: can you let me know how..because the body is limited

Comment: You can edit your question add.